# EaseInOut on MouseMove

Tags: jquery, background, jquery-animate, mouse, onmousemove

Okay, I have this jQuery code working. The background moves to the right place when moving the mouse. Now the only thing I want is an ease in and out on the moving backgound called 'boat'. Here's the code. Thanks in advance.

---

```
var stageWidth = $('#Stage').width();
var stageHeight = $('#Stage').height();

// boat
var boatMinPosX = -100;
var boatMaxPosX = -900;
var boatMinPosY = -100;
var boatMaxPosY = -400;

// sunset
var sunsetMinPosX = -180;
var sunsetMaxPosX = 0;

sym.onMouseMove = function( pageX, pageY ){
// move boat
var boatRequestPosX = sym.getTranslation(0, stageWidth, boatMinPosX, boatMaxPosX, pageX);
var boatRequestPosY = sym.getTranslation(0, stageHeight, boatMinPosY, boatMaxPosY, pageY);
sym.$("boat").css({left:boatRequestPosX, top:boatRequestPosY});


// testing
var boatPosX = sym.$("boat").css("left");
console.log('boatPosX'+boatPosX);


}


// utility function
/*
@param      
* minInput          minimum Number of  input scale
* maxInput          maximum Number of  input scale
* minOutput         minimum Number of  output scale
* maxOutput         maximum Number of  output scale
* inputNumber       Number in input scale to be translated
*/
sym.getTranslation = function(minInput, maxInput, minOutput, maxOutput, inputNumber) {      
var translatedVal = ((inputNumber - minInput) * (maxOutput -minOutput)/(maxInput - minInput) ) +          minOutput;
return translatedVal;   
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate more

Comment: I hope someone can improve the code. So the background, which is called 'boat', will have an ease in and out motion when moving the cursor.